# How do I iterate though a list to see if any value in the list matches part of a value in another cell?

Tags: python, excel

I have a list of US states from the US library. I am trying to then loop through a column in an excel file, to see if any cells in that column contain any US states. If it does, then I will delete those rows.

```
excel_file = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet')

states = us.states.STATES

for i in range(len(excel_file['Column Label'])):
    if any(states) in excel_file['Column Label'][i]:
        print(i)
```

Right now I have a print statement in the loop just to see which indexes pop up, but the loop itself isn't working. I am receiving this error.

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not bool

Comment: What does the `any` method documentation tell you about its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) does. `any()` loops over an iterable and returns `True` if any of the things in that iterable result in `True`.

For example:

```python
any([False, False, False]) => False
any([False, True, False])  => True
```

To more easily read what you're trying to do, I switched to an [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) loop instead of range. This returns the index and the current value we're iterating over. For each entry in the sheet, we can then check if that entry is within your list of states.

The `print()` statement here prints both the `i` value and your entry that matched.

```python
for i, entry in enumerate(excel_file['Column Label']):
  if entry in states:
    print(i, entry)
```

Note: Python hides the fact that this exercise requires a nested loop. The top for loop is obvious, but the `in` keyword here is creating a loop of its own. It is comparing `entry` to each item in `states`, at least until it finds a match.

Comment: Oh thank you! I do have one more follow up question. The cells that the state list is comparing to may have a state in the cell, but not only the state. For example, one says "Florida RV Trade Association". How do I check to see if any of the cell has a state in it?

Comment: You'd have to do another nested loop. You can do `'string' in 'much longer string'`, so something like `for state in states: if state in entry`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below,The `any()` function returns `True` if any item in an iterable are true, otherwise it returns `False`:

```
any(state in excel_file['Column Label'][i] for state in states)
```